# Python Prevent Same Loop

Tags: python, arrays, glob

Sorry if my question is duplicate. Because I can't find related to my question (or I miss the question, sorry about that)

FYI, this is my file :

```
BLP33 8172192873.xlsx
BLP31 3612739412.xlsx
BLP3 3612738402.xlsx
BLPR73 9173913823.xlsx
BLPR12 8172367132.xlsx
BR8 1827328367.xlsx
BR23 5928721983.xlsx
```

I'm trying to loop excel files with glob using var loop

```
var = ["BR*.xlsx", "BLPR*.xlsx", "BLP*.xlsx"]

for fly in var:
 for f in glob.glob(fly):
  print f
  print "--"
print "Clearly done."
```

Please have a look at BLP* and BLPR*, that's when the problem begin. When I loop BLP*, script will show BLPR files too. I can't figure how to separate BLP AND BLPR loop. Anybody know how?

This is the result, sorry forgot to attach

```
BLP33 8172192873.xlsx
--
BLP31 3612739412.xlsx
--
BLP3 3612738402.xlsx
--
BLPR73 9173913823.xlsx
--
BLPR12 8172367132.xlsx
--
BLPR73 9173913823.xlsx
--
BLPR12 8172367132.xlsx
--
BR8 1827328367.xlsx
--
BR23 5928721983.xlsx
--
Clearly done.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if not fly.startswith('BLPR')`

Comment: where do I put this script? @StephenRauch

Comment: You asked how to separate 'BLP' and 'BLPR'.  This is how.

Comment: Wait, I'll keep posted

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
import glob
var = [f for f in glob.glob("*.xlsx") if "br" in f or "blpr" in f or "blp" in f]
for f in var:
    print f
```